# Can't play sounds in Java

Tags: java, resources, directory, audio

I am trying to add sound effects to my Java game and I am failing to do so. I made the Sound class, I have the .wav files but for some reason I can't hear the sound and I am getting several errors about my code, unknown source or something, I am not sure about that. I will provide you guys with the Sound class, my class calling and the errors.

My folders look like this:
"...\Java Workspace\SpaceShooter\src" - For my Java .class files.
"...\Java Workspace\SpaceShooter\src\sounds" - For my java sounds.
The IDE I'm using is Eclipse.

This is the Sound class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class Sound {
    public static final Sound laser = new Sound("sounds/laser.wav");
    private AudioClip clip;

    public Sound (String filename){
        try{
            clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(filename));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(){
        try{
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    clip.play();
                }
            }.start();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call my Sound class.

```
...
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
    if (!player1weapon.isFalling){
         player1weapon.isFalling = true;
         Sound.laser.play();
    }
```

---

And the errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Unknown Source)
    at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:10)
    at Sound.<clinit>(Sound.java:5)
    at SpaceInvadersPanel$4.keyPressed(SpaceInvadersPanel.java:71)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Sound$1.run(Sound.java:20)
```

Comment: Skip the thread. clip.play() doesn't block. It just starts playing the clip and returns immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Unknown Source)
```

The error occurs here:

```
clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(filename));
```

so either filename is a nullpointer or the return value of Sound.class.getResource(filename) is a nullpointer.

Try to debug checking those values by printing them and see what they are.

```
Sound sound = Sound.class.getResource(filename);

System.out.println(sound);
System.out.println(filename);

if (filename != null && sound != null) clip = Applet.newAudioClip(sound);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I understand what you mean but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Nevermind, I got what you mean and it works. You're my hero, thank you.

Comment: I made an edit, basically just verify the objects to use are not null, because that is what the compiler told you: nullpointer.